# Как объединить две preg_match_all() в одну?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть две довольно сложные `preg_match_all()` команды. Обе анализируют URL страницы и выдергивают из него разные значения.

```
preg_match_all('/-([\d\|]{1,})\-(a\d{1,}|c)?\//', $fullUri, $searchMatch, PREG_SET_ORDER)
preg_match_all('/(ss|p\d{1,4})\-(.+?)\//', $fullUri, $searchStringMatch, PREG_SET_ORDER)
```

Выражения работают правильно и так, как надо. Вопрос не в них.
Далее по коду мне было бы удобнее, чтобы все выдернутые данные были в одной переменной...

Вопрос: как их объединить в одно большое выражение?
Надо учитывать, что `$fullUri` может содержать ответ как для одного из выражний, так и для обоих одновременно.

Пробовал просто рядом написать и разделить `|` - сработало не совсем так, как надо. Вторая часть содержит больше сегментов ответа, т.к. в начале выражения есть другие скобки.
Можно ли как-то объединить выражения, чтобы они фактически были одним выражением, но обрабатывались как отдельные?

---

Добавлю конкретики.

Вот URL: `$fullUri = '/en/ss-dress/16-8-a2/black-114-a3/pg2/';`

Первая регулярка

```
preg_match_all('/-([\d\|]{1,})\-(a\d{1,}|c)?\//', $fullUri, $searchMatch, PREG_SET_ORDER)
```

выдергивает элементы `16-8-a2` и `black-114-a3` и возвращает их как два массива по 3 элемента

```
array(2) {
    [0]=> array(3) {
        [0]=> string(6) "-8-a2/" 
        [1]=> string(1) "8" 
        [2]=> string(2) "a2" 
    } 
    [1]=> array(3) { 
        [0]=> string(8) "-114-a3/" 
        [1]=> string(3) "114" 
        [2]=> string(2) "a3" 
    } 
}
```

Вторая

```
preg_match_all('/(ss|p\d{1,4})\-(.+?)\//', $fullUri, $searchStringMatch, PREG_SET_ORDER)
```

выдергивает еще один параметр: `ss-dress` и тоже возвращает его как массив с 3 элементами:

```
array(1) { 
    [0]=> array(3) { 
        [0]=> string(9) "ss-dress/" 
        [1]=> string(2) "ss" 
        [2]=> string(5) "dress" 
    } 
}
```

Теперь объединяем выражения в одну и выводим.

```
preg_match_all('/-([\d\|]{1,})\-(a\d{1,}|c)?\/|(ss|p\d{1,4})\-(.+?)\//', $fullUri, $searchMatchAll, PREG_SET_ORDER);
```

Результат:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>array(5) {
    [0]=>string(9) "ss-dress/"
    [1]=>string(0) ""
    [2]=>string(0) ""
    [3]=>string(2) "ss"
    [4]=>string(5) "dress"
  }
  [1]=>array(3) {
    [0]=>string(6) "-8-a2/"
    [1]=>string(1) "8"
    [2]=>string(2) "a2"
  }
  [2]=>array(3) {
    [0]=>string(8) "-114-a3/"
    [1]=>string(3) "114"
    [2]=>string(2) "a3"
  }
}
```

В принципе, в результате все те же данные, однако `ss-dress` теперь массив из 5-ти элементов (из-за того, что регулярка, ловящая это, стоит вторая в очереди). Это не смертельно и с этим можно работать (уже работаю)... Однако главный вопрос:

Можно ли как-то объединить обе регулярки, чтобы возвращаемый архив был по структуре одинаков для всех своих элементов?

Comment: А что именно не работает? Я просто добавил знак `|` между ними и у меня почему-то все отработало с небольшими замечаниями, которые в принципе логичны: вторая часть идет с нумерацией не с 1, а с 5, т.к. до этого в выражении есть скобки, а нумерация частей идет с самой первой скобки

Comment: @ВОРОН да, вы правы. Сработало (видимо я что-то не очень аккуратно сделал). Однако сработало не совсем идеально. Я исправил вопрос...

Comment: А что мешает убрать эти несколько пустых записей во втором массиве? Тем более если вы знаете сколько именно записей надо пропустить.

Comment: Да не, убрать не проблема (уже делаю :) ) . Но хотелось бы знать, можно ли заставить выражения игнорировать предыдущие скобки, если выражение - сложносоставное из двух или более маленьких...

Comment: Какой результат должен быть на тексте: `-p1234-5678/` ?

Comment: Зря голосуете за закрытие. Задача поставлена конкретно и не требует глобальных уточнений.

Comment: @ReinRaus, голосовал потому-что не понятно, что должно быть в результате при объединении регулярок. Автор вопроса не предоставил тестовый массив входных строк и ожидаемых им результатов.

Comment: @Visman - Я добавил конкретики...

Comment: @cyadvert, потестируйте https://regex101.com/r/wY9hU4/1 Если подойдет, оформлю ответом.

Comment: @Visman - работает. Спасибо. Оформляйте. В общей картине у меня есть еще пару параметров - попробую добавить сам. Не получится - постучусь за помощью :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Предлагаю использовать такое регулярное выражение

```
/(ss|p\d{1,4}|(?<=-)[\d\|]+)\-(a\d+|c|.+?)\//
```

В нем обе ваших регулярки разделены на две части относительно `-`. Отсюда может получиться некоторая накладка, когда, например, к первому элементу равному `ss` пройдет второй элемент равный `a2` из такой строки `/ss-a2/`.

**UPD**

Регулярное выражение можно упростить до

```
/(ss|p\d{1,4}|(?<=-)[\d\|]+)\-(.+?)\//
```

Этот вариант аналогичен первому.